# Make the 'Related' sidebar links prioritize questions matching *all* tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, questions

Although SE in general considers tags to be equal, we have some tags (like [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements)) that are usually only valid when paired with another tag for a particular game or series.

However, the code for suggesting related links doesn't take this into account. For example, say I am viewing a question on a particular Diablo 3 achievement (tagged [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) and [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements)). The 'Related' widget may be suggesting [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements) questions from other games, such as Mass Effect or Skyrim, when it *should* prioritise other Diablo 3 achievement questions instead.

This may be kind of a unique feature request based on Arqade's domain, but I think it'd work better if 'Related' sidebar links gave more importance to having other tags in common.

We should also consider not allowing questions to be tagged with *only* [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements) (no idea if there are such posts or how to search for them)

Comment: Hmm, I'm also not aware of a way to easily search for posts with a single tag.  And I agree that questions are more likely to be related the more tags they share (assuming tagging is working as intended, *cough*) here and elsewhere.

Comment: So a question tagged `c` and `strings` has questions tagged both `c` and `strings` show up in its related question list instead of `strings` and `java`? Sounds like a good idea!

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Yes, and thanks for clarifying the question to make it more generic. My 2nd point is a bit different though, just want to point out to readers - it is not related to point 1